# logout implementation with KeycloakOIDCFilter

Tags: keycloak

I am getting started with securing my webapp using KeycloakOIDCFilter ,

For logout my application  redirects to url

> http://auth-server/auth/realms/{realm-name}/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=encodedRedirectUri

,    this clears the session in keycloack,  but application continues to show secured pages,   and this filter pulls security information  (SerializableKeycloakAccount) from cache.

by removing KeycloakAccount.class.getName()  attribute   from session   and redirect to auth-server 
is  redirecting to login page , and preventing acces to  secured pages after logout,

Is this how logout should be implemented ?

This filter also   has PreAuthActionsHandler, this has handleLogout ,  should application use this ?